# Binary Classifier with training data for one label only

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In some real-life problems such as authentication, we only have training data for one label (x is authenticated) while the other label doesn't have any data or only few entries (x is an imposter).

What kind of changes should we do in order to adjust a classifier to deal with a label targeted for other/unknown entries?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that you have a lot of missing *labels*, correct?  You still have predictor variables for the unknown entries?

Comment: Only one missing label. A binary classifier with 1=authorized as John Doe, -1= Imposter of John Doe. I only have the training data made by John Doe, so all the training points that I have are f(x)=1.

Comment: Take the example of Speaker Recognition. I only train it on my voice to authorize me, but I don't have any data for imposters that try to pretend to be me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a widespread situation, for example in industrial quality control, you want to decide whether a batch of product is fit for sale. Also medical diagnosis (if it isn't a differential diagnosis) often faces the same problem.

So-called [one-class or unary classifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification) address this. The idea is to model the "in" class independently of possible other classes.

In chemometrics, [SIMCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_independent_modelling_of_class_analogies) is a popular approach to this. Basically, you compress your class into a PCA models and then develop a boundary outside which you deem it sufficiently improbable that the case belongs to that class. (For multiple independent classes, you do this for each class separtely.)

[D.M. Tax: One-class classification -- Concept-learning in the absence of counter-examples, Technische Universiteit Delft, 2001](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/n9d04/thesis.pdf) develops a one-class SVM.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have many data for class A (auth.) and almost any for class B (imposter) in your (randomly chosen?) training set?

From [Wikipedia (Pseudocount)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocount),

> In any observed data set or sample there is the possibility, especially with low-probability events and/or small data sets, of a possible event not occurring. Its observed frequency is therefore zero, apparently implying a probability of zero. This is an oversimplification, which is inaccurate and often unhelpful, particularly in probability-based machine learning techniques such as artificial neural networks and hidden Markov models. By artificially adjusting the probability of rare (but not impossible) events so those probabilities are not exactly zero, we avoid the zero-frequency problem. Also see Cromwell's rule.

So I would therefore artificially include some data for the other, very rare label/class.

Comment: I added some comments to clear the question (sorry for ambiguity) but you've understood me correctly. So do I need to add noise or random adjustments for the authorized training data to generate imposters data? Am I correct?

Comment: So you don't have ANY data for the imposters? Not even in your whole population (because usually, training data is a random sample from the population)? I don't know what to do in that case, then maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes, I don't have any data for imposters. The training data that I have only contain some metrics to authorize different users.

Comment: Maybe you should post some example data so people can fully understand what you're trying to achieve.